# Нужна ли запятая со словом "думаешь"?

Tags: пунктуация, запятые

*1. Сколько(,) думаешь(,) ей лет?*

*2. Думаешь(,) им нужна наша помощь?*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(1) *Сколько, думаешь, ей лет?*  (2) *Думаешь, им нужна наша помощь?*

В этих предложениях запятыми обособляется **вводное предложение** "думаешь" (односоставное, определенно-личное).

**Правила:**

Розенталь: Вводные предложения, пункт 1.
http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=123#pp123

ПАС: Знаки препинания при вводных словах, сочетаниях слов и предложениях
http://orthographia.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=127#pp127, примечание 1(г)

Comment: Спасибо. Хочу уточнить: если писатель убирает все запятые "для удаления паузы" и ссылается на "авторскую пунктуацию", то можно ли считать это ошибкой?

Comment: Вы имеете  в виду эти предложения? Авторская пунктуация – это не есть авторский произвол, отклонение от правил необходимо объяснить. В данном случае такого грамматического объяснения нет. Что касается пауз, то на них не всегда можно ориентироваться. В частности, при обособлении вводных слов они не всегда слышатся явно – об обособлении скорее можно судить по ударению на вводном слове, которое на слух фиксируется более четко: ДУмаешь, им нужна наша пОмощь? СкОлько, дУмаешь, ей лЕт?

Comment: спасибо за ответ.